# Improving parallelization in Numba

Tags: python, numba

I have a function in Numba with several loops that could be parallelized. The loop writes to a common array, K, so I understand that the compiler might not be optimizing as much as it could. 
However, I have no feel for what will make numba's jit compiler create the most efficient code. The examples in the documentation are too simplistic to be of help.

I have tried changing each of the `range` into `prange`. The best results were obtained when parallelizing the loop over `k_x`, but I only got a 2.8x improvement on a machine with 4 cores. I know that I should not expect linear performance improvements, but I have the feeling that I should get better results in this case. For example, I get slightly better results using dask, `x_cond.map_blocks(cond_expect_kernel, x_tr, *args)` which is odd considering the scheduler overhead.

**Is there a way to improve the parallelization of this function beyond simply changing `range` into `prange`?**

Original function

```
@jit(float64[:,:](float64[:,:], float64[:,:], int64, int64), nopython=True, nogil=True)
def cond_expect_kernel(x_cond, x_tr, degree, amount_non_cond_vars):
    size = x_cond.shape[1]
    x_tr_cond = x_tr[:, :size]
    samples_x = x_cond.shape[0]
    samples_tr = x_tr.shape[0]
    K = (1+np.dot(x_cond, x_tr_cond.T))**degree

    for j in range(size, size+amount_non_cond_vars):
        for k_x in range(samples_x):
            for k_x_tr in range(samples_tr):
                K[k_x, k_x_tr] += x_tr[k_x_tr, j]**2*3 
                for j_left in range(size):
                    K[k_x, k_x_tr] += x_cond[k_x, j_left]*x_tr[k_x_tr, j_left]*x_tr[k_x_tr, j] ** 2 *3  
    return K
```

Best parallel version so far:

```
@jit(float64[:,:](float64[:,:], float64[:,:], int64, int64), nopython=True, parallel=True)
def cond_expect_kernel_parallel(x_cond, x_tr, degree, amount_non_cond_vars):
    size = x_cond.shape[1]
    x_tr_cond = x_tr[:, :size]
    samples_x = x_cond.shape[0]
    samples_tr = x_tr.shape[0]
    K = (1+np.dot(x_cond, x_tr_cond.T))**degree
    for j in range(size, size+amount_non_cond_vars):
        for k_x in prange(samples_x):
            for k_x_tr in range(samples_tr):
                K[k_x, k_x_tr] += x_tr[k_x_tr, j]**2*3 
                for j_left in range(size):
                    K[k_x, k_x_tr] += x_cond[k_x, j_left]*x_tr[k_x_tr, j_left]*x_tr[k_x_tr, j] ** 2 *3  
    return K
```

For reference, I am working on a machine with 4 cores and another with 16 cores. `samples_x` is around 100,000, `samples_tr` around 50000, `size` around 3, and `amount_non_cond_vars` around 100.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few performance critical issues.

- You are declaring your input and output arrays as non-contiguos eg. this would be the decaration of a C-contigous array `nb.float64[:,::1]`. This often prevents SIMD- vectorization and can in many cases lead to lower performance. If you are not sure if the arrays are C-contigious simply don't the declare it, Numba can do this itself.
- If some reductions are in your code use a scalar summation variable and copy the results at the end to the array. Uneccesary reading/writing to shared arrays have to be avoided.
- Think of your memory access pattern/ loop ordering. If you do something wrong here you would end up in a memory bottleneck quite early.
- If something like `size` is quite often 3, you can write a specialised version for this problem. (In this case manual loop unrolling). You can check with a small wrapper function if the specialised case occurs.

**Examples**

```
import numpy as np
import time
import llvmlite.binding as llvm
llvm.set_option('', '--debug-only=loop-vectorize')
@nb.njit(nb.float64[:,:](nb.float64[:,:], nb.float64[:,:], nb.int64, nb.int64),fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def cond_expect_kernel_gen(x_cond, x_tr, degree, amount_non_cond_vars):
    x_tr_cond = x_tr[:,:x_cond.shape[1]]
    K =  np.dot(x_cond, x_tr_cond.T)

    for k_x in nb.prange(x_cond.shape[0]):
        for k_x_tr in range(x_tr.shape[0]):
          sum=(K[k_x, k_x_tr]+1)**degree
          for j in range(x_cond.shape[1], x_cond.shape[1]+amount_non_cond_vars):
            sum += x_tr[k_x_tr, j]**2*3 
            for j_left in range(x_cond.shape[1]):
                sum += x_cond[k_x, j_left]*x_tr[k_x_tr, j_left]*x_tr[k_x_tr, j] ** 2 *3
          K[k_x, k_x_tr]=sum
    return K

@nb.njit(nb.float64[:,::1](nb.float64[:,::1], nb.float64[:,::1], nb.int64, nb.int64),fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def cond_expect_kernel_3(x_cond, x_tr, degree, amount_non_cond_vars):
    assert x_cond.shape[1]==3
    x_tr_cond = x_tr[:,:x_cond.shape[1]]
    K = np.dot(x_cond, x_tr_cond.T)

    for k_x in nb.prange(x_cond.shape[0]):
        for k_x_tr in range(x_tr.shape[0]):
          sum=(K[k_x, k_x_tr]+1)**degree
          for j in range(x_cond.shape[1], x_cond.shape[1]+amount_non_cond_vars):
            sum += x_tr[k_x_tr, j]**2*3
            sum_2=0.
            sum_2 += x_cond[k_x, 0]*x_tr[k_x_tr, 0]
            sum_2 += x_cond[k_x, 1]*x_tr[k_x_tr, 1]
            sum_2 += x_cond[k_x, 2]*x_tr[k_x_tr, 2]
            sum+=sum_2*x_tr[k_x_tr, j] ** 2 *3
          K[k_x, k_x_tr]=sum
    return K
```

**Performance**

```
x_cond=np.random.rand(10_000,3)
x_tr=np.random.rand(5_000,103)
amount_non_cond_vars=100
degree=3

t1=time.time()
res_1=cond_expect_kernel_gen(x_cond, x_tr, degree, amount_non_cond_vars)
print(time.time()-t1)
t1=time.time()
res_2=cond_expect_kernel_3(x_cond, x_tr, degree, amount_non_cond_vars)
print(time.time()-t1)

(Quadcore i7, Numba 0.40dev)
your version, single threaded: 40s
your version, parallel: 8.61s

mod_general:3.8s
mod_3: 1.35s
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I got 5x to 10x improvements depending on hardware and matrix size. I learnt a lot, thanks. I knew the reductions would be a problem but I did not know how to improve them. What is this part doing --debug-only=loop-vectorize? Why debug-only? Should I carry this to the final code or was it only for your test?

Comment: @Luk17 No, it shouldn't be in the final code. It gives debug information on what the SIMD-vectorizer is doing. https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/user/faq.html 1.13.2.3